# For loop in R to run Chi_square test on all columns

Tags: r, dataframe, for-loop

```
head(Data)
                       
          Gene1 Gene2 Gene3 Gene4 Gene5 Gene6 Gene7 Gene8 
  SAMPLE1   0    1      0      0     0     1   1     1          
  SAMPLE2   0    1      0      1     0     1   0     1        
  SAMPLE3   0    0      0      1     0     0   1     1          
  SAMPLE4   1    0      0      0     1     0   0     0
```

I am running fisher test and chi square test like following

```
Gene7_Gene8<- table (Data[, c ("Gene7", "Gene8")])
chisq.test( Gene7_Gene8) and 
fisher.test(Gene7_Gene8)
```

How can i run the chisq.test by `for loop` in all the data sets at once. I am looking for p.value against each possible pair of gene in my data set. (my original data has around 60 columns)

Comment: Hey. Help us helping you.
Please provide a subsample of your data, that is,
a piece of code we could all copy-paste and analyse ourselves, and then help you.
I have a feeling this can be done using the map function,
something in the midst of nesting your data according to each gene, and then run a map function over you different smaller data frames

https://towardsdatascience.com/coding-in-r-nest-and-map-your-way-to-efficient-code-4e44ba58ee4a
Like in this example.

So just provide us with detailed code chunck we can copy to our environemnt, and help is on the way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No `for` loop is required, we can do them as such:

```r
com <- data.frame(t(combn(colnames(Data), 2)))
com
#       X1    X2
# 1  Gene1 Gene2
# 2  Gene1 Gene3
# 3  Gene1 Gene4
# 4  Gene1 Gene5
# 5  Gene1 Gene6
# 6  Gene1 Gene7
# 7  Gene1 Gene8
# 8  Gene2 Gene3
# ...

chisq <- apply(com, 1, function(i) chisq.test(table(Data[,i]))$p.value)
# Warning in chisq.test(table(Data[, i])) :
#   Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
# Warning in chisq.test(table(Data[, i])) :
#   Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
# Warning in chisq.test(table(Data[, i])) :
#   Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
# ...

chisq
#  [1] 1.0000000 0.3173105 1.0000000 0.5049851 1.0000000 1.0000000 0.5049851 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 0.3173105
# [12] 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 0.3173105 1.0000000 1.0000000 0.3173105 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000
# [23] 1.0000000 1.0000000 0.5049851 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000
```

For the fisher test, we run into some problems:

```r
fisher <- apply(com, 1, function(i) fisher.test(table(Data[,i]))$p.value)
# Error in fisher.test(table(Data[, i])) : 
#   'x' must have at least 2 rows and columns
```

This is because not all tables are 2x2, so we need to catch that error and return something meaningful. I suggest `NA`:

```r
fisher <- apply(com, 1, function(i) tryCatch(fisher.test(table(Data[,i]))$p.value, error = function(e) NA_real_))
fisher
#  [1] 1.0000000        NA 1.0000000 0.2500000 1.0000000 1.0000000 0.2500000        NA 1.0000000 1.0000000 0.3333333
# [12] 1.0000000 1.0000000        NA        NA        NA        NA        NA 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000
# [23] 1.0000000 1.0000000 0.2500000 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0000000
```

From here, we can easily combine them:

```r
out <- cbind(com, chisq=chisq, fisher=fisher)
out
#       X1    X2     chisq    fisher
# 1  Gene1 Gene2 1.0000000 1.0000000
# 2  Gene1 Gene3 0.3173105        NA
# 3  Gene1 Gene4 1.0000000 1.0000000
# 4  Gene1 Gene5 0.5049851 0.2500000
# 5  Gene1 Gene6 1.0000000 1.0000000
# 6  Gene1 Gene7 1.0000000 1.0000000
# 7  Gene1 Gene8 0.5049851 0.2500000
# 8  Gene2 Gene3 1.0000000        NA
# 9  Gene2 Gene4 1.0000000 1.0000000
# ...
```

While `combn` does have the `FUN=` argument, I found it easier to reuse the results for the `fisher.test` automation as well. It also clears up the output (in my mind) since it clearly shows which genes are considered in each comparison.

Comment: Thanks, its the perfect solution i was looking for. Can you please explain the command "chisq <- apply(com, 1, function(i) chisq.test(table(Data[,i]))$p.value)". Sorry for being naive but i m learning R

Comment: `apply(com, 1,` calls a function on each row of a matrix or frame, with the whole row as a single argument (`function(I)`). I'm this case, a row is two strings, a pair of column names, e.g., `c("Gene1","Gene3")`. We subset `Data[,I]`, then compute its `table(.)`, then it's `chisq.test(.)` but only keep the `$p.value` from that call.

Answer (score 3):

We may use `combn`

```
lst1 <- combn(seq_len(ncol(Data)), 2, function(i) 
   FUN = chisq.test(table(Data[, i])), simplify = FALSE)
names(lst1) <- combn(colnames(Data), 2, FUN = paste, collapse = "_")
```

Comment: Upvote but instead of `seq_len(ncol(.))`, I would use the simpler `names(Data)` .

Comment: @RuiBarradas `names` can be an issue as we don't know whether the OP had a matrix or data.frame.  instead `colnames` could work in both cases. Thanks

Comment: I've never used the `FUN` parameter inside of the `combn` function before.  This answer is very clever.

Comment: This returns a nested array with no indications of which pair is which (we can know this, but it's not intuitive), and no clear way to extract the p-value from each test. I like the `FUN=` method of `combn`, it'd be nice if we could adapt it to be a bit less vague in its reporting.

Comment: The fundamental issue is that OP's data frame is not tidy (information necessary to complete the analysis is contained in their column names).  Make the data tidy and the problem becomes much simpler to solve.  Address the cause, not the symptom.  This is an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

Answer (score 3):

I hope this works out for you.
[image]

```
# This is a fake dataset similar to the one in the Opening post:
df <- data.frame(
  
  gene1 = sample(c(0,1),10,T),
  gene2 = sample(c(0,1),10,T),
  gene3 = sample(c(0,1),10,T),
  gene4 = sample(c(0,1),10,T),
  gene5 = sample(c(0,1),10,T)
)
rownames(df) <- paste0("sample",1:nrow(df))



# ldf stands for long df, and is a longer version, which will make it easier to analysie.
ldf <- df %>% pivot_longer(cols = everything(),names_to = "gene_type",
                           values_to = "true_false") %>%
  arrange(gene_type)
# ndf stands for nested df, and is the already nested-by-genes data frame we will analyse
ndf <- ldf %>% nest_by(gene_type)

# Here we create a new colum named p_value and in the map() function
# we extract the p values from a chiq.test erformed on each gene
ndf$p_value <- map(ndf$data,~chisq.test(table(.x))$p.value) %>% unlist()


# Now we have our final data frame and can further anlyse and create plots.
final_df <- ndf %>% unnest(cols = data)
final_df %>% group_by(gene_type) %>% summarise(p.value=mean(p_value)) %>% 
  mutate(is_significant=p.value<0.05)

# In my personal opinion, leaving the data frame in a long version is best suited for further anlysis.

final_df %>% group_by(gene_type) %>% summarise(p.value=mean(p_value)) %>% 
  mutate(is_significant=p.value<0.05) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=gene_type,y=p.value,color=is_significant))+
  geom_text(aes(label=gene_type),show.legend = F)+
  labs(title = "P values of different genes")+
  theme_minimal()
```